# fetch is not defined in D3 csv call

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to get a D3 example running but It appears d3-fetch doesn't seem to export a fetch. But text.js does. I added d3-fetch using npm.
I'm a little confused. Running this in VS Code.

This is the calling code:

```
driving = d3.csv("driving.csv");
```

from text.js:

```
export default function(input, init) {
  return fetch(input, init).then(responseText);
}
```

........

```
ReferenceError: fetch is not defined
    at default (file:///C:/D3Test/node_modules/d3-fetch/src/text.js:7:3)
    at Module.<anonymous> (file:///C:/D3Test/node_modules/d3-fetch/src/dsv.js:7:12)
    at file:///C:/D3Test/scatter.mjs:180:26
```

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install node-fetch
```

and

```
import fetch from "node-fetch";
```

if you get an error "type": "module" in package.json